# Get collected message before time limit in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is there a way to receive messages from discord.js collectors before the time limit expires?

I tried using collector.on collected, but it triggered after the time limit I set.

Here is what I currently have:

```
this.collected = false
        this.collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msg.channel, m => m.author.bot === false,{time: 10000});
        this.collector.on('collect', message =>{
            if(!this.collected){
                this.collected = true
                console.log(message)
                msg.channel.send(message.content)
                this.collector.stop()
               //Insert the same thing here(Copy+Paste the same code here)
            }
        });
```

(The this on everything is for globality, it's because it has to be recursive)

I want the collector to emit an event on the moment it receiveves the first message, but with the current code it only does that after the time limit.

Comment: the *collect* event should be called everytime the collector detects a message that passes the filter, so you don't have to wait for timeout to get the collected messages. What happens if you remove the `if (!this.collected)`condition ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to add that I need to collect only one message, anyways, It goes through all messages, I need only one message to be collected.

Comment: the collector.stop() should, as it says, stop the collector; So your condition seems a bit redundant to me. Otherwise, your code seems fine to me, I don't get why it's not working as intended. What does your comment `\\Insert the same thing here` mean btw ? Is there more code that you didn't include in your question ?

Comment: Yes, it has to be recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it appears that the [`collect`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=e-collect) event is only emitted *after* the set [`time`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions) option is reached. It seems as though it's not actually collecting the messages when they're received, but instead when the timer runs out. Whether this is intentional or not, I'm not sure.

Since you only need a certain amount of messages, you can set the [`maxMatches`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageCollectorOptions) option of your collector. Then, if that amount of messages is collected before the `time` limit is reached, the collector will emit the `collect` event and stop.

```js
this.collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msg.channel, m => !m.author.bot, { maxMatches: 1, time: 10000 });

this.collector.on('collect', message => {
  msg.channel.send(message.content)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: The .first() will crash since the collected variable contains the message, not a collection

Comment: My bad, edited the code. I was thinking of [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages).