# Discord.js Status Time Elapsed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am using Discord.js Node V12
I am currently trying to find out how to say **time elapsed** in the status to show how long the bot has been online. But i cannot find anyone who has asked or answered any of these questions

Comment: Anything here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668985/get-collected-message-before-time-limit-in-discord-js Maybe you can use time stamps as show here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151017/discord-js-bot-rate-limit

Comment: I think that is the only thing i may be able to do, but that is another step forward to what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `client.uptime` to get the amount of time your bot has been online (since it last booted up) in milliseconds. You can then take those milliseconds and convert them into whatever unit of time you choose. Here's an example, converted to hours:

```
var uptime = client.uptime; //in milliseconds
var hours = uptime / 1000 / 60 / 60 ; //milliseconds -> seconds -> minutes -> hours
```

If you're referring to how long the bot has been up since the first time you ever started it up, that's an entirely different answer, and you would need to clarify further on that. But if you just want total online time elapsed since the bot was last offline, this is the answer.

If you are using this in a command, you can retrieve `client` from the `message` object, like so:

```
var uptime = message.client.uptime; //in milliseconds
var hours = uptime / 1000 / 60 / 60 ; //milliseconds -> seconds -> minutes -> hours
```

I do not know why you could not find the answer, if my understanding of your question is correct, because this information can be found easily on this website and on [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org).

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=uptime
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client